# Automatically Update Excel Sheets From Multiple Work Books

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with two main sheets with values based off 24 other sheets.

24 employees will send their sheets weekly with new data. The main workbook should combine them into the main file. Formatting and everything.

I have used this code:

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

It works to combine them. The problem is I need the data from the 24 sheets to overwrite the data in the 24 sheets in the main workbook. If I delete the 24 sheets from the main workbook, it kills the formulas on the main sheet.

Comment: So there is only data coming in; no formulas being copied  into the original? What about worksheet names... do they match?

Comment: Don't link the formulas to sheets in the master book. Link it to each of the 24 books so when you run your macro, master sheet gets updated. Edit: to clarify, your macro won't need the copy line. Just need to open/close.

Comment: Findwindow - So linking to the individual sheets sounds like a better idea. I will do that.
However, you said I wont need the copy line. What would I use instead to open all the other sheets into the main sheet? The manager wants to be able to select each sheet at the bottom of his main workbook.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am having is I need the data from the 24 sheets to
>   overwrite the data in the 24 sheets in the main work book

Well, in this case, why not just copy/paste the values, without removing and copying entire sheets. I suppose that each source sheet has a corresponding sheet with the same name in the Master workbook:

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
       Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
       For Each src In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
           Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(src.name)
           dest.UsedRange.ClearContents
           src.UsedRange.Copy dest.Range(src.UsedRange.Address)
       Next src
       Workbooks(Filename).Close
       Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I like that idea. I tried that code. however, I keep getting the error
1004
"all merged cells need to be the same size. Which is weird because all 24 sheets were copied directly from the main sheet.

Comment: So you have merged cells in the sheets? Umm, that may be requires to change the copy method. Would you try as edited? (We will copy the range as is, together with its merged cells)

Comment: I tried the new code and it works great! Thanks! Solved my issue.

Comment: One more quick question. On this part:

'code'
    Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
'code'

Is there a way I can change that to open all the files in a folder named "FPT Project Sales Trackers" that is housed in the same folder as the main workbook? 

I tried the ActiveDirectory.Path one but it wasn't working.

Comment: I figured it out. Everything works now. Problem solved